# How to select top records by parameter or if the parameter is not given then send all?

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I have a procedure which returns the nearest vehicle between point vehicle and customer and customer can choose how many vehicles can see. Now i want o create procedure which do the same but when parameter is not given must result all records.

My procedure looks like this:

```
create procedure p_top5_v2_type2222ROW
    @IdCustomer int,
    @idGroupVehicle int,
    @ResultCount int 
as
    declare @start geography
    set @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer = @idCustomer)

    select top(@ResultCount)    
        idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight,
        maxSpeed, nameLocation 
    from 
        Vehicle 
    where 
        idGroupVehicle = @idGroupVehicle  
        and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 is not null)
    order by 
        @start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 asc
GO
```

and result is:

[image: 1]

Now I want to create when resultcount is not give result is all records but can someone explain how to do I must use `if @ResultCount is null @ResultCount = *` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want o create procedure which do the same but when parameter is not given must result all records.

A typical way to solve this is:

```
where (idGroupVehicle = @idGroupVehicle  or
       @idGroupVehicle is null
      ) and
      @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null
```

The use of `OR` like this in the `WHERE` clause often has performance implications.  In this case, though, the query looks pretty complicated, so it might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this that

```
create procedure    p_top5_v2_type2222ROWRRR2222
 @IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int,
 @ResultCount int=null as
 declare @start geography
  SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
  if @ResultCount is null
  select  idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
else
select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use If else like below:

```
create procedure    p_top5_v2_type2222ROW
 @IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int,
 @ResultCount int as
 declare @start geography
        IF @ResultCount>0 
             select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
        from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
        order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
        Else
                    select idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
            from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
```

Comment: May I know the reason behind downvoting this answer? It's a correct answer.

Comment: If any of the answered helped you please accept that to mark this question as answered.